# OpenShift Docker login issue

Tags: docker, registry, redhat, openshift-origin

I have set up a local OpenShift instance and installed the docker registry according to the Red Hat instructions. I am having trouble logging into the internal docker registry, however. I'm sure it is some gap in my understanding of how Docker and/or OpenShift works. I have given my user the admin, cluster-admin, and system:registry roles, which is what I believe I need. I login via oc, and then attempt to log into the registry like so:

```
docker login -u $(oc whoami) -e 'xxxxxx' -p $(oc whoami -t) $(hostname):8443
```

and I get the following response:

```
Error response from daemon: Unexpected status code [403] : {
    "kind": "Status",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {},
    "status": "Failure",
    "message": "User \"system:anonymous\" cannot \"post\" on \"/v1/users/\"",
    "reason": "Forbidden",
    "details": {},
    "code": 403
}
```

I'm not finding much about this particular error message, so I'm not sure what the heck I'm missing.

Comment: Is your docker registry address "$(hostname):8443" ? It seems like that is web console address

Comment: omg. You are right. Gah. I thought I was actually getting somewhere. I've been trying to login using the internal ip and 5000 port, but it just seems to hang. Thanks. I'll close this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have been using the internal docker IP:

```
# oc get svc docker-registry -n default
NAME              CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
docker-registry   172.30.10.52   <none>        5000/TCP   9h
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing the docker registry outside the openshift cluster. Theses are the things you will have to do.

Create a route for the service (either from cli or web console).
`oc create route --service=<registryName>`
If you are using self signed certs, add this route to your host machine's insecure docker registry options (depends on what host machine you are using).
Then try doing a docker login to the docker registry.
You said you installed a registry inside openshift, they already have a docker registry running inside openshift.